Finding the point of intercept when projecting a circle along a vector
Imagine you have something like a platonic solid in one hand and a cookie cutter in the other. You centre the cookie cutter on a vertex and cut a cylindrical hole through the solid. We are just look for the point along one of the edges where it got sliced.

The cookie cutter is a circle with radius "r".
You translated it perfectly in the direction of vector "V"
The circle was perfectly aligned with the plane that is orthogonal to V
Point "A" is a point along the projected centre line of the circle.
Point "B" is a point that was definitely outside the projected radius of the circle

What would be the formula to find the point along segment AB where it intersects the projected circle.

I don't understand the role played by the platonic solid. Your issue could (seemingly) be plainly phrased like this : "Being given a cylinder with axis the $z$ axis, with radius $r$, $A$ is placed at the origin, and $B$ is a point outside the cylinder, determine the point such that ... etc...", isn't it ?

@JeanMarie Yes, probably the plutonic solid doesn't help since I'm only trying to intercept one line segment. However, it is important that the cylinder's axis could be on any vector.

Let us assume that the axis of the cylinder is defined by unit norm vector $\vec{V}$.
Besides, it can be assumed WLOG that $A$ is taken as/at the origin. Let
$$W:= \vec{AB}.$$
It is known that the projection of vector $W$ onto an axis directed by a unit vector (here $V$) can be written
$$(W . V)V$$
where $W . V$ stands for the dot product.
Therefore, the distance of $B$ to the cylinder axis is the norm of the difference between $W$ and $(W . V)V$ :
$$\delta:= \|W-(W . V)V\|\tag{1}$$
If we call $C$ the point of intersection of $W=\vec{AB}$ with the cylinder with radius $r$, a proportionality reasoning gives :
$$\vec{AC}=\frac{r}{\delta} \vec{AB}$$

Edit : Translation of above formulas into coordinates :
If the coordinates of $V$ are $p,q,r$ with $p^2+q^2+r^2=1$,
and the coordinates of $B$ are $x,y,z$, then  :
$$W-(W . V)V=\pmatrix{x-(px+qy+rz)p\\y-(px+qy+rz)q\\z-(px+qy+rz)r}$$
giving $$(x-(px+qy+rz)p)^2+(y-(px+qy+rz)q)^2+(z-(px+qy+rz)r)^2=k^2  \ \text{with} \ k=\delta$$
(the above equation can be interpreted as the generic equation of all cylinders with a common axis directed by $\vec{V}$).

Just added an "Edit" with vector formulas written in terms of coordinates.

Any comment ?...
